# How to remove a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a "Student" Table which contains a "StudnetId" column which goes like this:

```
StudentId

S1
S4
S3
S5
S1
S2
S3
```

With SQL, how can you remove a character based on the index of the character.

Specifically, I need to remove the "S" for each row in this column when updating the table.

Comment: This question is too specific, like "Why is the red car outside my window honking at me".  Will anyone else in the world have this problem?  You should also mention what version of SQL you are using.  Oracle?  Mysql?  Other?  What is the datatype of the column you want to parse?  Char[2]  varchar?  BLOB??  I suggest reading the FAQ for StackOverflow.  Specifically the section on how to ask good questions.

Comment: UPDATE Student SET StudentId = REPLACE(StudentId, 'S', '')
is very simple method (2nd answer). Do you need something else @user1517628? If yes comment please

Comment: @EricLeschinski. That's good way to teach a low reputed person rather than direct down-voting. Most part of the comment is very helpful. However I think mysql is confirm from the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE Student SET StudentId = REPLACE(StudentId, 'S', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

This will remove the first character from each row for in that column.

```
UPDATE Student SET StudentId = SUBSTR(StudentId, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really remove a character from a value stored in a column. You have to assign an entirely new value to the column, which can be derived using an expression that references the currently stored value.

Here's an example of a statement that will "remove" a leading 'S' character from the StudentId column:

```
UPDATE `Student`
   SET `StudentId` 
        = IF(SUBSTR(`StudentId`,1,1)='S',SUBSTR(`StudentId`,2),`StudentId`)
```

Note that if the first character of StudentId is other than 'S', the value will not be changed. Likewise, this statement will achieve the same result:

```
UPDATE `Student`
   SET `StudentId` = SUBSTR(`StudentId`,2)
 WHERE SUBSTR(`StudentId`,1,1)='S'
```

Other solutions (which don't check if the first character is an 'S') will achieve the same result, given specific conditions for the data (e.g. if we can guarantee that the first character of every value is an 'S'.  Using a `REPLACE` function handles the case where the leading character is not an 'S', but it will potentially remove more than the leading 'S' (if we don't have some sort of guarantee that the character 'S' does not appear anywhere in any value except the first position.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show not to affect rows in db use below;

```
SELECT REPLACE(StudentId, 'S', '') FROM Student;
```

if you want to update db:

```
UPDATE Student SET StudentId = REPLACE(StudentId, 'S', '');
```